# Magento equivalent to MovableType's FieldDay

Tags: product

Does anyone know an equivalent to the MovableType plugin FieldDay(https://github.com/movabletype/mt-plugin-field-day/wiki/Basics) for Magento. I need to be able to create multiple instances of product field sets. (i.e. multiple instruction blocks)

Comment: I dont see any difference between this and the Attributes set in Magento. You might not be aware of the use, but i think what you ask is doable with an attribute set.

Comment: So having multiple instances of an attribute set for a product set is possible?

Comment: You can have one attribute set per product if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom attribute, with a custom renderer.
You will find [here an example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38445/146) about how to create an attribute that supports a custom renderer with 2 fields. You can extend that to support a dynamic number of fields.
You can also take a look at how the tire prices functionality is built. I think it's similar to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Magento allows to have multiple custom product fields (attributes) per product.
   See admin > catalog > manage attributes > attributes
2. As in one store you can sell different type of products, with different fields, magento allows for each product define it's own attribute set.  See admin > catalog > manage attributes > attributes

When you creating or edit attribute, you can specify "Show on Product View Page" to be "Yes".

Comment: I think this would be more complicated than using new attributes. It'd be more like having more instances of a group of attributes (not like an attribute set that can get used only once). Example, I'd have a set of fields that would have "instruction" , "image", "link" as "instruction group". I may need to have multiple instances of this group for a product with ability to add or remove said instances at will.

Comment: What about grouping attributes by tabs like at our site http://amasty.com/magento-abandoned-cart-email.html ?  Demo links, change log, description they all are just product attributes.