# How to change module name in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, template

I am new in magento and I have made a module with the help of this plugin [Easylife_Attr](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38445/13832).

In this module I am unable to change display name in admin product tab and template title (See Image).

Now,How can I change display name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that it is the correct way or not, but I have solved this issue by changed field "attribute_group_name" value in table "eav_attribute_group" and my issue is solved.

[image]