# how to create custom Attribute in admin html

Tags: magento-enterprise

how to  create custom Template for custom product.
I have to create minimum order quantity and customer group under custom template.when the product is edited

Comment: You should add more details to the question about what exactly is your issue, only then, others will be able to help. In it's current state, the question is way too unclear and might get closed.

Comment: need to create only custom Attribute to product right?

Comment: i have to create minimum order quantity  per product to customer group. how could i do this.Please help me

Comment: I follow the link.http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38434/adminhtml-how-to-add-custom-template-for-custom-product-attribute... but in this Attribute is not visible. how could i solve this. Observer is called.but the issue is Attribute is unvisible in the product grid.... but i need the same window like the above link. Some one Please help me

Comment: are you need display this custom attribute in admin side product grid right?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can create attribute please visit link:
```

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html#gref

```
<?php $minQty = $_product->getMinqty() ; ?>
    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($minQty) ? $minQty : max($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1, 1) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am new to magento . please tell me where should i place this code.

Comment: this will be add in product view page.
text box you show is use for the product view page. and you have to first create attribute "minqty". than try to debug.

Comment: how to create custom template for custom product

Comment: you have to use app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml for product view page.