# Add new tab in product edit page and call custom phtml in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2.1.0

I want to add new tab in product edit page and for that i have follow this steps :

1. Create `di.xml` and add below code:

   ```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="custommodule" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Custommodule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customtab</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
   ```
2. Create `Customtab.php` and by `modifyMeta()` function new tab is
   created.

Now I want to call custom phtml file to render html. How can I call custom phtml file ?

Comment: Hello, I am doing something kind of same. Did you get the way? Kindly update the ans if you have. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Thanks Jaimin, today it helps me a lot to resolve issue :) +5 from me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have take reference for configurable product and followed below steps. Here may be some code is not usable.

**1) Create** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="modulename" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customtab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

     <type name="Namespace\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customtab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="formName" xsi:type="string">product_form</argument>
            <argument name="dataScopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
            <argument name="dataSourceName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form_data_source</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2) Create** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Modifier/Customtab.php`

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

class Customtab extends AbstractModifier
{
    const SORT_ORDER = 40;

    protected $locator;

    protected $websiteRepository;

    protected $groupRepository;

    protected $storeRepository;

    protected $websitesOptionsList;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $websitesList;

    private $dataScopeName;

    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        WebsiteRepositoryInterface $websiteRepository,
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        $dataScopeName
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->websiteRepository = $websiteRepository;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->dataScopeName = $dataScopeName;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        if (!$this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $meta = array_replace_recursive(
                $meta,
                [
                    'tabname' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-product-customclass',
                                    'label' => __('Your Label'),
                                    'collapsible' => true,
                                    'componentType' => Form\Fieldset::NAME,
                                    'sortOrder' => $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                        $meta,
                                        'search-engine-optimization',
                                        self::SORT_ORDER
                                    ),
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'children' => $this->getPanelChildren(),
                    ],
                ]
            );
        }

        return $meta;
    }

    protected function getPanelChildren()
    {
        return [
            'tabname_products_button_set' => $this->getButtonSet()

        ];
    }

    protected function getButtonSet()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'component' => 'Namespace_Modulename/js/components/container-tabname-handler',
                        'formElement' => 'container',
                        'componentType' => 'container',
                        'label' => false,
                        'content1' => __(
                            'Add some content'
                        ),
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                        'createTabButton' => 'ns = ${ $.ns }, index = create_tabname_products_button',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [

                'create_tabname_products_button' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $this->dataScopeName.'.customModal',
                                        'actionName' => 'trigger',
                                        'params' => ['active', true],
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $this->dataScopeName.'.customModal',
                                        'actionName' => 'openModal',
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'title' => __('Your Title'),
                                'sortOrder' => 20,

                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**3) Create** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block name="product.form.modulename.matrix" class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Variations\Config\Matrix" template="Namespace_Modulename::catalog/product/edit/tab/custom.phtml" as="product_custom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true" />
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1000</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form_data_source</item>
                        <item name="form" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</item>
                        <item name="modal" xsi:type="string">customModal</item>
                        <item name="nameStepWizard" xsi:type="string">variation-steps-wizard</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">productFormCustommodule</item>
                        <item name="urlWizard" xsi:type="string">modulename/index/custom</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**4) Create layout file for action** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/modulename_index_custom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Custom" template="catalog/product/edit/tab/customfile.phtml" name="product_custom">

        </block> 
    </container>
</layout>
```

**5) Create block file** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Custom.php`

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab;


class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/tab/custom.phtml';


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**6) Create controller file for action** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Custom.php`

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_errorHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context           $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory      $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('product_custom');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

**7) Create template file** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/tab/custom.phtml`

```
<div class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/dataScope') ?>" data-role="step-wizard-dialog" data-bind="scope: '<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getForm() ?>.<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getModal() ?>'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/dataScope') ?>" id="product-variations-matrix" data-role="product-variations-matrix">
    <div data-bind="scope: 'configurableVariations'"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/form') ?>.<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getModal() ?>": {
                        "component": "Namespace_Modulename/js/components/modal-custommodule",
                        "options": {"type": "slide", "title": "<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Title')); ?>"},
                        "formName": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getForm() ?>",
                        "isTemplate": false,
                        "stepWizard": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/nameStepWizard') ?>",
                        "children": {
                            "wizard": {
                                "url": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getUrl($block->getData('config/urlWizard'), ['id' => $block->getProduct()->getId()]) ?>",
                                "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/components/html"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    require(['jquery', 'mage/apply/main'], function ($, main) {
        main.apply();

          $('.<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/dataScope') ?>[data-role=step-wizard-dialog]').applyBindings();
        $('.<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/dataScope') ?>[data-role=product-variations-matrix]').applyBindings();

    })
</script>
```

**8) Create my custom phtml file** `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/tab/customfile.phtml` and write my code here.

**9) Create Js** `app/code/Namesapce/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/modal-custommodule.js`

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal-component',
    'uiRegistry',
    'underscore'
], function (Modal, registry, _) {
    'use strict';

    return Modal.extend({
        defaults: {
            stepWizard: '',
            modules: {
                form: '${ $.formName }'
            }
        },

        /**
         * Open modal
         */
        openModal: function () {
            var stepWizard = {};

            this.form().validate();

            if (this.form().source.get('params.invalid') === false) {
                stepWizard = registry.get('index = ' + this.stepWizard);

                if (!_.isUndefined(stepWizard)) {
                    stepWizard.open();
                }

                this._super();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**10 ) Create Js** `app/code/Namesapce/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/container-tabname-handler.js`

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Element) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            listens: {
                '${ $.provider }:data.is_downloadable': 'handleProductType'
            },
            links: {
                isDownloadable: '${ $.provider }:data.is_downloadable'
            },
            modules: {
                createConfigurableButton: '${$.createConfigurableButton}'
            }
        },

        /**
         * Invokes initialize method of parent class,
         * contains initialization logic
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.handleProductType(this.isDownloadable);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Calls 'initObservable' of parent
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe(['content']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Change content for container and visibility for button
         *
         * @param {String} isDownloadable
         */
        handleProductType: function (isDownloadable) {
            if (isDownloadable === '1') {
                this.content(this.content2);

                if (this.createConfigurableButton()) {
                    this.createConfigurableButton().visible(false);
                }
            } else {
                this.content(this.content1);

                if (this.createConfigurableButton()) {
                    this.createConfigurableButton().visible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Will your code validate fields also?

Comment: yes my code validate fields.

Comment: ok Thanks. I will check and will let you know.

Comment: Its working fine

Comment: I have used above logic and it works fine  with Magento 2.1.x version but it is not working with Magento2.2 version. Please provide me soluton.

Comment: I think catalog_product_new.xml in not working because app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/tab/custom.phtml is not calling.

Comment: in Magento 2.2, you have to create product_form.xml file under view/adminhtml/ui_component and add block in this file

Comment: Still not working... I have created product_form.xml and put layout xml code into that.

Comment: Here is the step by step guide https://goo.gl/FWcEqF