# Add new custom tab with grid selection in product detail page admin : Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have followed [Add new tab in product edit page and call custom phtml in Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122957/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-and-call-custom-phtml-in-magento-2-1) But i wants to add custom grid selection into the modal!
Share me best solution for this...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are using Magento 2.1 version?

Comment: Yes, i am using magento 2.1 and i can see blank modal after followed to given link @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: You should take a look this module: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation

Comment: Thanks @KhoaTruongDinh Let me look into this! Get in touch with me Thanks again :)

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh this link is helpful for me!! Thanks a lot...

Comment: I am getting more confusing because overrided the related products class here. I needs to show custom grid using custom table collection into modal. Please help me for same? Thanks!