# Add new tab in product edit page in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, product, tabs, product-edit

I want to add new tab in product edit page and for that i have follow this steps :

1. Create di.xml and add below code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="modulename" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customtab</item>
                       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </virtualType>
       <type name="Namespace\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customtab">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="formName" xsi:type="string">product_form</argument>
               <argument name="dataScopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
               <argument name="dataSourceName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form_data_source</argument>
           </arguments>
      </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. Now I want to call custom phtml file to render html. How can I call custom phtml file ?

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122957/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-and-call-custom-phtml-in-magento-2-1 already ans i think

Comment: Try these Link   https://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-tab-product-page-magento2/ @meet

Comment: Rama Chandran this answer is only create custome filed but button is not working.

Comment: I have Create Filed in Product Grid not at Product View page @  Pranay K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found One Solution So Please Check it this link "https://github.com/meetvora1021/Product-Edit-Tab/tree/master/app/code/Meet/Productgridextend"

Answer (score 5):

Create **product_form.xml** file in app/code/VendorName/NameSpace/view/adminhtml/ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="fieldname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">{{Tab name}}</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="fieldname_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">VendorName\NameSpace\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Tabs\Demo</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Create **Demo.php** in app/code/VendorName/NameSpace/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tabs

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\NameSpace\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Tabs;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
class Demo extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'demo.phtml';

    protected $_systemStore;

    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Actions');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Actions');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getReqest()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    }
}
```

Create **demo.phtml** file in app/code/VendorName/NameSpace/view/adminhtml/templates

Comment: i have to create custom tab in edit grid and also open pop-up of grid but i have open my custom grid open in this grid so any one can solution?
I have Follow this link "https://github.com/meetvora1021/Product-Edit-Tab/tree/master/app/code/Meet/Productgridextend" for solution and create filed and also open pop-up.

Comment: how to disable tab on specific conditions? I have tried return false on canshowtab() method. It's not working